# Need to use flash player on react-electron-web-view

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, electron

I'm developing a react-electron application and I'm using react-electron-web-view which is using browserify to display the website. The problem is that some websites still using flash player and the application shows the "Get Adobe Flash Player" icon and is not loading. How can I add and use flash player? Any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Electron freeze sometimes when using pepper flash, so i redevelop using nw.js and the problem solved.. Thanks